# How to go down (recursively) in UIPath

Tags: uipath

I want to go down recursively and automatically at the host and clusters tab (the blue one in the picture), and then take the text like guest os, compability, etc.

[image: the example]

I already know how to get the text from summary, but I got the problem to loop (go down) at the host and cluster tabs. 
Any idea how to do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I already tried from this tips but I can't find solution https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-select-loop-dynamic-elements/21410

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best idea to have one robot do everything - i.e. setting filters, parsing results, clicking on each result, parsing data, then going back, and so on. Instead of that approach, divide and conquer. Create multiple sequences/workflows, each one with one specific task in mind.

Here's how I would tackle it:

- Create a sequence that opens the target page, setting the filters (e.g. Germany, as mentioned in your link: https://www.autoscout24.de/ergebnisse?cy=D&powertype=kw&atype=C&ustate=N%2CU&sort=standard&desc=0&page=1&size=20)
- Have the same robot extract the link for each result. Don't go into the details, this could potentially be the task of another robot.
- Have the links stored in a queue. Read more about [Queues and Transactions](https://orchestrator.uipath.com/docs/about-queues-and-transactions) here.
- Create another sequence that takes the next item in the queue and open the stored link. This will take you directly to the results page (e.g. https://www.autoscout24.de/angebote/opel-corsa-12v-city-servo-ahk-benzin-silber-84a66193-b6d6-4fc9-b222-ec5a7319f221?cldtidx=1)
- Parse any kind of data you need.

This comes with the benefit that you can use multiple robots at the same time extracting data, potentially increasing scraping significantly. The Queues and Transactions feature will make sure each result is visited only once, and that multiple robots don't process the same item multiple times.

Edit: you might want to start with [ReFramework](https://github.com/UiPath/ReFrameWork), which I'd recommend.